# jquery-ui sortable connected lists with hidden overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two fixed hight divs each containing a sortable list which are connected to each other. Is there a way to hide the overflow while still having the lists connected? E.g. if the overflow is set to hidden then the li doesn't show when it is dragged outside of the div.

I know a possible solution would be to calculate the maximum number of li that the div can contain and dynamically add/remove elements based on the number of visible elements, but I was wondering if there was a better solution?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to fix this by using [the `appendTo` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-appendTo), which will tell it where to attach the helper object to in the DOM. The default is to use `parent` which means the helper that's being dragged is inside your `overflow: hidden` div. Changing it to, for example, `body` should fix it for you. I.e:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ appendTo: 'body' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `containment`. It defines a bounding box that the sortable items are constrained to while dragging.

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment

Comment: no, that only contains the boundaries of which the element can be dragged.